# Como hacer que los datos personalizados de producto simple aparezcan en el administrador listado productos Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

En Woocommerce, en Productos simples he creado dos nuevos campos personalizados:
Direccion y Categoria (pueden ser otros nombres, no es relevante )
y en el box he agregado un texto a cada uno de ellos.

Como puedo hacer que tales textos aparezcan en el admninistrador del listado productos?

Les agradeceria me pudieran ayudar, gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Hay un filtro para agregar columnas [`manage_{$screen->id}_columns`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_screen-id_columns/) a un listado del backend, el `$screen-id` de un listado para editar CPTs en el admin es `edit-{$post->post_type}`, el filtro expone un array de columnas al que podes setear o unsetear elementos.

En el caso del listado en el backend de productos de woocommerce, `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product`, el filter quedaría `manage_edit-product_columns`.

```php
add_filter(
  'manage_edit-product_columns',
  'SOes366763_agregar_columnas',
  15
);

function SOes366763_agregar_columnas( $columns ){
  // slug/key columna, título a mostrar traducible: __( texto, text domain )
  $columns['direccion'] = __( 'Dirección', 'mitema-wc' ); 
  $columns['categoria'] = __( 'Categoría', 'mitema-wc' );

  // para borrar la columna "date"
  unset( $columns['date'] );

  return $columns;
}
```

Luego hay un action para rellenar esas columnas por cada item [`manage_{$post->post_type}_posts_custom_column`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_post-post_type_posts_custom_column/),  este action expone el nombre/key de la columna y el id del post.

En el caso de productos de woocommerce quedaría : `manage_product_posts_custom_column`.

```php
add_action(
  'manage_product_posts_custom_column',
  'SOes366763_rellenar_columnas',
   10, 2
);

function SOes366763_rellenar_columnas( $column_name, $post_id ) {
  switch ( $column_name ) :
    case 'direccion' :
      // si el key de $column_name es igual al slug/id del meta se puede usar $column_name
      echo get_post_meta( $post_id, '_prod_direccion', true ); 
    break;
    case 'categoria' :
      echo get_post_meta( $post_id, '_prod_categoria', true );
    break;
  endswitch;
}
```

( un `switch`/`case` o varios `if` va a gusto y cantidad de columnas a procesar )

Tener en cuenta que puede haber algunos campos protegidos o calculados dentro del producto de woocommerce, en ese caso hay que usar las funciones propias de wc, por ejemplo para listar el peso con unidad de peso:

```php
  $producto = wc_get_product( $post_id );
  $producto_peso = $producto->get_weight();
  if ( $producto->has_weight() ) {
    echo $producto_peso . get_option( 'woocommerce_weight_unit' );
  }
```